# Exceptions are not caught

Tags: c++, exception

There are few questions with similiar problem, but most of them are resolved with removal of throw() after function declaration, so those are not solution to my problem (probably).

I make resource manager for my future projects in SFML 2.1 so I need some error handling there.

ex. I've got the method:

```
sf::Music & cResourceManager::getMusic(const std::string & key) {
    if(key.empty()) throw std::invalid_argument("empty key");
    return MusicObject;
}
```

It seems to be meaningless but it's just for testing purposes now.

Then in main():

```
try {
    RESOURCE_MANAGER.getMusic("");
} catch (const std::runtime_error &ob) {
    std::cout << ob.what() << std::endl;
} catch (const std::invalid_argument &ob) {
    std::cout << ob.what() << std::endl;
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "unknown error\n";
}
```

Obvious outcome is (is it?) that getMusic() will throw invalid_argument() and it should be caught by catch(const std::invalid_argument &b) or atleast by catch(...) but instead of catching it and displaying "empty key" or "unknown error" it just displays:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

What can be source of such strange behaviour?

@edit
I'm using code::blocks.

Comment: `key.compare("") == 0` should really just be `key.empty()`. It's a lot clearer. Even using `key == ""` looks a lot better, but go with `empty`.

Comment: That's probably not a C++ exception, but a runtime error (a.k.a. a crash). Run your program in a debugger and it will catch it.

Comment: [Works here](http://ideone.com/eiYwku). I suspect your `MusicObject` is not a valid object any more? Can you show where that comes from?

Comment: Exceptions like access violations do not inherit from std::exception (at least in visual studio) so play() could be throwing something like that.

Comment: i've updated the question with `empty()` and removed `play()` to be sure it's not the reason. No change. If I managed to debug it the proper way, Code::Blocks throws SIGSEGV in `std::string::size() const () ()` in Debugger "console"

Comment: That shows that this is not an exception, you have somehow managed to produce an invalid string object. Is the code you have posted above `RESOURCE_MANAGER.getMusic("")` exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Code::Blocks thorows SIGSEGV on empty string because STL inlines size() and it can't find the funciton. It is a known issue and unrelated.

Compile with out any optimizations and no function inlining to enable debugging.

Comment: One possible reason for exceptions not being caught is if they're thrown in a different thread.

Comment: Look in these threads about how to debug properly. Being able to debug properly is key to writing code efficiently : http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17573.0

Comment: @odedsh Thanks, gonna check it out for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some "comment out" researches and testing again. Outcome is pretty embarrassing coz I've got caught in my own laziness & time trap. I managed to find out that SFML objects were causing the troubles so it was time to check all the project and C::B settings. After clearing them (deleting config file blah blah) it started to work ("magic") so after investigating both clear and my old config files I've found the real troublemakers - linker settings:

> -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

and since I've compiled SFML as dynamic version... the obvious conflict occured.

Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for all your tips.